# What, and how can, topological invariants can be computed from a space's algebra of functions?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

The Gelfrand duality says that the category of locally compact Hausdorff spaces (with proper continuous functions) is equivalent to the category of commutative $C^*$ algebras (with proper $*$-homomorphisms).  For instance, of $X$ is such a topological space, then $C_0(X) = \{f: X\to \mathbb{C}, f$ is continuous and $f$ vanishes at $\infty \}$ is its related $C^*$ algebra.  We can go the other way by looking at a $C^*$ algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and taking its set of characters $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{A},\mathbb{C})$ under pointwise convergence to recover the topological space.

So say one has a commutative $C^*$ algebra $\mathcal{A}$, how does one recover topological invariants, like say, the number of connected components of $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{A},\mathbb{C})=X$, from $\mathcal{A}$ itself?

Is this even possible?  Or am I wrongly asserting that equivalence of categories says something about the individual objects?

**edit** many responses focus on the number of connected components, which I appreciate, but that was only meant as an example of the sort qualitative info I would like to recover. Can we recover the singular homology of $X$ from $\mathcal{A}$ ? The fundamental group? Is X metrizable?

Comment: This is relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82708/do-subalgebras-of-cx-admit-a-description-in-terms-of-the-compact-hausdorff-spa. In particular, the number of connected components comes from the number of idempotent elements $C_0(X)$.

Comment: Of course it is possible: the algebra determines the space $X$ completely (up to isomorphism in its category)—this is preciely what having an equivalence means— so anything you may want to know about $X$ can be seen in $A$ somehow.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, the question is clearly on how to concretize the NCG dictionary for commutative algebras.   Do you know references beyond Connes' book?

Answer (score 4):

The Boolean algebra of connected components is equivalent to the projections (the elements with $p^2=p$) in the algebra of functions, with multiplication of functions representing intersection and $(p_1,p_2) \to p_1 + p_2 - p_1p_2$ being the union of sets of components.

I think there is a version of algebraic K-theory for topological algebras whose value on $C_0(X)$ is the topological $K$-theory of $X$.

Connes' book on NCG has more of the dictionary but also omits many basic things.

Comment: It's not really clear to me why you would call idempotent elements "projections", because in the equation "$p^2 = p$", the square isn't the composition $p^2 = p \circ p$ (which wouldn't even make sense, since the domain and the codomain of $p$ disagree), it's literally the square $p^2(x) = p(x) \cdot p(x)$ with the multiplication of $\mathbb{C}$. As a general remark, I'd also like to point out that $p_1 + p_2 - p_1 p_2 = 1 - (1 - p_1)(1 - p_2)$ isn't random: it comes from $A \cup B = \overline{\bar A \cap \bar B}$ and $1 - p$ corresponds to the complement.

Comment: It's pretty standard in English when discussing operator algebras to refer to solutions of p^2=p as "projectors".  For example, continuous dimension in a von Neumann algebra is "trace of a projector".  On MSE I figured "projection" would be more recognizable.   Of course the formula for union is not arbitrary and indeed I derived it when posting in the manner you wrote down.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but an operator algebra is something that basically deals with **endo**morphisms, no? And the square is the square in the sense of composition. It's a completely different sort of equation when you take the square of a *functional* $A \to \mathbb{C}$... The terminology "idempotent" is much more adapted. (The remark about the formula for the union was more directed at other readers who could wonder where it came from, not you.)

Comment: You already made that point in the first comment.  And it was answered in the second: although there is nothing wrong with the word "idempotent", the word "projector" (or projection) can also be used for solutions of $x^2=x$ in a not necessarily commutative ring R, and such $x$ "project" onto one of the two subrings into which they split R as a direct sum.  For an algebra C(X), this splitting coincides with a splitting of X into two parts.  And multiplication-by-x is an **endo**morphism of the ring.

Comment: Then the projector is multiplication by $x$, not $x$ itself. But I can see that this discussion is going nowhere, so I'll stop here.

Comment: "**We will, therefore, also not be too nitpicking and use the words 'idempotent' and 'projection' sometimes as synonyms.**"  ---- Roch et al, *Noncommutative Gelfand Theories* ( p121,  https://books.google.com/books?id=cewJCk6GzXkC&pg=PA121  ) .  They do point out one thing not written above, which is that projection in an operator (or involutive) algebra can also mean that $p$ is self-adjoint with respect to the involution (while also being a solution of $p^2=p$).  I have never heard anyone make the distinction between $x$ being a projector and multiplication by $x$ being one.

Comment: @ASCIIAdvocate: Linguistitc questions aside, you should clarify what you mean by "equivalence" of algebras. Projections in $C(X)$ are the characteristic functions of clopen subsets and not all clopen subsets are connected components of $X$.

Comment: do you have a reference for the proof of this fact? Or shall I start hunting through Connes' tome?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: pointwise multiplication of functions becomes composition when they are seen as multiplication operators over the Hilbert space $L^2(X)$. That's the standard point of view in Operator Algebras, which is the context of this question.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know whether it will help you much, you may view a dictionary between topological concepts and their equivalent algebraic concepts on pages 6 and 13 of ["Very Basic Non-commutative Geometry" by Masoud Khalkhali](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~bisch/ncgoa04/talks/masoud_khalkhali.pdf).